# Checking whether the given Cartesian product has the least upper bound property or not .

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

**Problem**

a)Does $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ in the dictionary order have the least upper bound property ?

b)What about $[0,1] \times [0,1)$ ?

c) What about $[ 0,1)\times [0,1]$?

My understanding of dictionary order -

An order relation $<$ on $A\times B$ is defined:

$(a_1,b_1) < (a_2,b_2)$ if $a_1 <_A a_2$, or if $a_1 = a_2$ and $b_1 <_B b_2$.

It is called dictionary order relation on $A\times B$.

How to proceed ?

$Attempt$

Let X = [0,1]×[0,1]

> > Suppose that A$\subset$ X is a nonempty subset with upper bound.
> >     X<sub>o</sub> := {$x\in[0,1]|\exists y\in[0,1]:(x,y)\in A$} $\subset$ [0,1] .
> >     X<sub>o</sub>  has the least upper bound x<sub>o</sub>. 
> >     Y<sub>o</sub>:= {$y\in[0,1]$|(x<sub>o</sub>,y)$\in$ A} $\subset$ [0,1] .
> >     If Y<sub>o</sub> is empty (x<sub>o</sub>,0) is the least upper bound . If 
> >     Y<sub>o</sub> is non-empty,then Y<sub>o</sub> is bounded above by 1,so (x<sub>o</sub>,y<sub>o</sub>) is the least upper bound of A.

Comment: Why downvote?..

Comment: x @blue: Probably because it looks like you're seeking to have your homework done for you without needing to understand the material yourself. Exercises like this are an invitation to puzzle it out in your own mind, and _thereby_ get a greater intuitive familiarity with the concepts; if you're just handed a solution you won't actually _gain_ any experience from it.

Comment: Also, out of sheer curiosity. How did you choose the tags for this question (and the other one you posted around the same time)?

Comment: Ok. I will try to show my work next time . I can see how it may seem so.

Comment: By the way i am not a mathematics major. This is not a part of my course or any assignment.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila tags seem appropriate to me.

Comment: Did you perhaps spend a few minutes reading the excerpts that you get when selecting the tags? How is this a question about foundations of mathematics? Or about set theory (as indicated by the tag excerpt)? Many people worked very hard on these things. Please show some effort on your side when you choose tags. Especially when they have this kind of information with them.

Comment: Sorry. I will try my best to use more appropriate tags from next time .

Comment: You can edit your question by adding some detail about your thought processes.  What is the least upper bound property?  What do you think is the answer to the first question?  Can you prove your guess?  If not, how far can you get?  What about the second question?

Comment: Your edit gives a good argument that $[0,1]^2$ has the least upper bound property. Does this argument work for $[0,1]\times [0,1)$ or $[0,1)\times[0,1]$ too? If not, what goes wrong? Can the argument be fixed to overcome this? Or, on the other hand, perhaps the way the argument fails can inspire you to think of a counterexample?

Comment: I have a intuitive notion that for b) lub doesn't exist.

Comment: But can't come with a mathematical argument.

Comment: @blueboy: To argue that one of the sets _doesn't_ have the least upper bound property, the standard approach would be to describe a concrete nonempty bounded subset of it that has no least upper bound.

Comment: Sure i will try this approach tonight.